# Delete a row(s) from MySQL using an HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am having difficulty deleting rows from my database.

I have a delete button in a form that when it is clicked then performs a DELETE FROM query but it doesnt work and Im wondering whether my theory is completly wrong (the theory being that having a form and submit button to INSERT data into a database works so why not use that to delete stuff? This is the code

```
$league_id = $_GET['id'];
$delete_entry = "<form action=\"".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."\ method=\"post\">
                <input type=\"submit\" name=\"ooops\" value=\"Delete Entries\"></p>
                </form>";

if ($_POST['ooops']) { //if the data is rubbish then delete and start again...

$delete_lge_sql = "DELETE FROM st_position WHERE league_id = '$league_id'";
$delete_lge_res = mysqli_query($statto, $delete_lge_sql)
                or die(mysqli_error($statto));
}
```

When I click Delete Entries the page reloads and the URL looks like this

page.php?ooops=Delete+Entries

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Please show your HTML *output*, not your PHP *source*.

Comment: @Diodeus in addition to the mysqli horrors?

Comment: Something else is going wrong before you even get to the deleting. The URL having `?ooops=Delete+Entries` appended to it does not fit with what your code shows. Your code shows your form as being a POST, so the URL shouldn't change. -- Are you sure the POST is going through properly? Run an echo after `if ($_POST['ooops'])` to make sure that the posted data is coming through properly.

Comment: Yup, nothing like setting yourself up for SQL injections.

Comment: There is a error in your code `action=\"".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."\ `  it should be `action=\"".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."\"` (note the extra " at the end) my guess would be this is blocking the method="POST", making it a GET from not a POST form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a double-quote in this statement

```
$delete_entry = "<form action=\"".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."\ method=\"post\">
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"ooops\" value=\"Delete Entries\"></p>
            </form>";
```

Change it to

```
$delete_entry = "<form action=\"".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."\" method=\"post\">
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"ooops\" value=\"Delete Entries\"></p>
            </form>";
```

Comment: Urgh! I knew it would be something like that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$delete_entry = "<form action=\"".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."\ method=\"post\">
                <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ooops\" value=\"1\" />
                <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete Entries\">
                </form>";
```

This way, your $_POST['ooops'] variable will be equal to "1". Just make your test on this value and it will be ok.